# python re-arrange elements in a list based on the sublist values

Tags: python, list, sorting, sublist, compare-and-swap

I have have a list of lists that I would like to re-arrange based on the values of its sublist.

```
list = [["c","d"], ["b", "c"], ["a", "b"], ["x", "y"]]
```

The final product should look like this:

```
new_list = [["a", "b"], ["b", "c"], ["c", "d"], ["x", "y"]]
```

The Python code should analyze each of the elements in `list` and re-arrange them into a `new_list`. Sublist with the same element should be placed side-by-side, for example `["b", "c"]` should be placed after `["a", "b"]` forming a chain of `["a", "b"], ["b", "c"]`.

Here is my attempt at getting the list sorted:

```py
for i in list:
  if len(new_list) == 0:
    new_list.append(i)
  else:
    for j in new_list:
      if j[0] == i[1]:
        newindex = new_list.index(j)
        new_list.insert(newindex, i)
```

Unfortunely, with the above code I am getting an infinite loop which is stuck at the else block.

Any suggestions on a better solution is most welcomed. Thank you.

Comment: In general you should not modify the contents of a list (inserting / deleting) while iterating over it. You can also use the built-in `sorted` with a custom key function.

Comment: Can't you just use the base list.sort() function? I think that will give the same result?

Comment: Your sort order seems underspecified. What if you  have sublists `[ "a"," b"], [ "a"," c"], [ "b","c"]`?

Comment: what should be the `new_list` for e.g. `list = [["b","m"], ["b","x"], ["b", "c"], ["a", "b"], ["x", "y"], ["m", "n"]]`? (that is - there is more then one path).

Comment: this might be a little similar to a [Topological Sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_sorting), deepens on what you want to do with parallel paths

Comment: John and Adam, it would be `["a", "b"], ["b", "c"], ["a", "c"]` and `["a", "b"], ["b", "m"], ["m", "n"], ["b", "x"], ["x", "y"], ["b", "c"]`. The same values should be next to each other

Comment: Unless your sublists partition into disjoint chains, this is still underspecified. For example, how would you handle the case where a given sublist is part of more than one chain?

Comment: @JonJ ` ["a", "b"], ["b", "c"], ["a", "c"] how come ["a"."c"] come here?

Comment: Excellent question. A sublist that exists as part of multiple chains is not likely, but possible. I have not done a thorough analysis on this.

Comment: Because `["b", "c"]` will be inserted after `["a", "b"]` due to element `b`. The same element of different sublists have to be side-by-side

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on @Adam.Er8 comment (I had the same idea, but his example is better than mine):

```
>>> L = [["b","m"], ["b","x"], ["b", "c"], ["a", "b"], ["x", "y"], ["m", "n"]]
```

The result is a forest. The idea is to build the trees from bottom to up, with a dict `child -> parent`:

```
>>> d = {}
>>> for u, v in L:
...     d[v] = u
...     if not u in d.keys():
...         d[u] = None
>>> d
{'m': 'b', 'b': 'a', 'x': 'b', 'c': 'b', 'a': None, 'y': 'x', 'n': 'm'}
```

Now, it's easy to reverse the trees:

```
>>> e = {}
>>> for k, v in d.items():
...     e.setdefault(v, []).append(k)
>>> e
{'b': ['m', 'x', 'c'], 'a': ['b'], None: ['a'], 'x': ['y'], 'm': ['n']}
```

With a DFS, you can output the paths:

```
>>> def dfs(x, stack=[]):
...     if x in e:
...         for y in e[x]:
...             yield from dfs(y, stack + [x])
...     else:
...         yield stack + [x]

>>> P = list(dfs(None))
>>> P
[[None, 'a', 'b', 'm', 'n'], [None, 'a', 'b', 'x', 'y'], [None, 'a', 'b', 'c']]
```

And finally:

```
>>> for p in P:
...     print(list(zip(p[1:], p[2:])))
[('a', 'b'), ('b', 'm'), ('m', 'n')]
[('a', 'b'), ('b', 'x'), ('x', 'y')]
[('a', 'b'), ('b', 'c')]
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. It's very helpful. I've learnt something new today.